patent attorney that mostly draft applications vs patent attorney that mostly do litigation
If one is looking for an attorney to draft a patent application, does it matter which of these two tasks the attorney perform mostly?

Patent attorneys are people who can do both but usually focus on one or the other.
As it happens, they are separate qualifications. To draft and prosecute patents one must be a registered practitioner with the USPTO. The requirements are an undergraduate degree in science or engineering and passing the all-day patent bar exam. No law degree needed.
Conversely, to litigate one must be a licensed member of the bar. No need to pass the patent bar test or have any technical background. Some great litigators were history majors.
If someone is a patent attorney, they have both qualifications.
I would suggest someone  who drafts and prosecutes patents for a living and who also keeps up with current CAFCA and SCOTUS cases.
